# Slow batch update on Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java-6, performance, batch-updates

I have a quite confusing and strange problem with using JDBC on an old Oracle server (which is an 8i as I was told). I prepared a table there with about 10 columns, numbers, varchars, a raw(255) and some dates in it, no restrictions, no keys, etc. On that side, everything is fast presumably. Afterwards, my application seemed to be really slow (inserting 25,000 data in about 30-50 seconds...). My environment is a nearly latest 1.6 JDK, ojdbc14 driver from a 10.2.0 Oracle.
So I cut out that code part and tested these things separately. Some background info on the code, here's the essential parts of it

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); // I tried with oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver too
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("thin url", "user", "pass");
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_STMT); // SQL_STMT is a simple <i>INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)</i> command with 10 parameters

for(int i = 0; i < numOfData; ++i) {
   pstmt.setObject(objects[i]); // objects has the data for example. I also tried setInt, setDate, etc with the corresponding types, does not speeds it up
   pstmt.addBatch();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
pstmt.close();
conn.close();
```

I think this is quite simple. I also tried this with a local H2 DB, that was superbly fast, took 0ms for even 500,000 data to insert it into the same structure (obviously not 0ms, just it was so fast that I could not measure it). I will try today with ojdbc6 and a newer oracle. My suspicion is that the ojdbc14 driver and jdk 1.6.idontknow has some problems with each other.

I traced down the ojdbc14 when working on the *executeBatch* with FINEST level and I saw thousands of conversions I think, *oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.stringToDriverCharBytes* and so on. Most of the time passed with these codes and just the last commands were the "real deal" as I saw. Commiting, parametering up the pstmt and so on was not slow, just the executeBatch.

FYI reading with  this old jdbc driver was fast, just the inserts were horribly slow.

So, any of you have an idea? What kind of driver I could use to make these fast and be compatible with all of the available DBs at least with some basic operations?

Comment: Are you comparing apples to apples?  For instance, if your Oracle instance is a remote server are you counting network latency times?

Comment: Well it is remote, but I have a comparison based on some previous projects and experiences with oracle db-s and to tell the truth, the code upstairs is obviously slower than expected. 
And I'm still on to find the cause if I have some time, I few days ago I tried this with a DB with the exact driver It needs, it was slow too, however not THAT slow than this. But that test was also beyond the expected speed.

Comment: Perhaps it's spending alot of time doing character encoding?  What encoding is on the server?

Comment: Hm this comment is worth to try and see, thanks.

Comment: What is the *driver's* version? (The 14 in ojdbc14.jar is the intended Java version, not the driver's version). I found that the 10.x drivers are *much* faster when it comes to batching than older drivers. Did you try one of the newer versions intended for Java6 ? (named ojdbc16.jar).

Comment: Another thing: do you have a lot of NULL values? I found that the driver is **much** faster if you use `setNull()` instead of `setObject(null)`

Comment: I tried ojdb6 too with a newer oracle DB, I had the same slow issues. To your second comment about setNull: obviously tried, I did not use the setObject for nulls because I think I had some exceptions. Or not, but anyways yeah, my current code uses setNull for nulls and that wasn't speed up it :(

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the possible latency with the "thousands of conversions", I would recommend using the Oracle OCI driver. It should be faster as it usually is for me since it is written in native code. Other than that, it is most likely a network latency issue.

Comment: Oracle itself claims (in the JDBC manual) that the thin driver is faster than the OCI driver.